# Perfect Runs of Consecutive Integers

Tags: nt.number-theory, prime-numbers, perfect-numbers

A run of 2 or more consecutive integers is said to be *perfect* if the sum of its terms equals the sum of all the their proper divisors, adding common divisors as often as they occur. For example, 672, 673 is such a run (672 is a triperfect number whose proper divisors add up to 1344, while 673 is a prime, 1 being its only proper divisor).

Are there arbitrarily long perfect runs of consecutive numbers? Infinitely many of any length greater than 1?

Comment: If $\sigma$ denotes the sum of divisors, then we have the classical estimate $\sum_{m=1}^n \sigma(m) \sim \zeta(2) n^2/2$. Since $1 < \zeta(2)<2$, this means that runs of $k$ consecutive integers $(n-k+1,\ldots,n)$ where $k$ is ``large'' (I think $k \gg \log n$ suffices) cannot be perfect.

Answer (score 6):

523776, 523777 is another example of a 2-run. Again, 523776 is a triperfect number.

An example of a 3-run is 5829840, 5829841, 5829842. No apparent pattern in these three numbers:

```
          Factorization         Sum of proper divisors
5829840   2^4 * 3^3 * 5 * 2699  14258160
5829841   29 * 53 * 3793        316439
5829842   2 * 2914921           2914924
```

Here are two more perfect 3-runs of consecutive numbers:

```
             Factorization                Sum of proper divisors
3414097920   2^16 * 3 * 5 * 23 * 151      8061430272
3414097921   13 * 31 * 41 * 206627        473814527
3414097922   2 * 1707048961               1707048964

39339578248  2^3 * 4917447281             34422130982
39339578249  29 * 4561 * 297421           1365596671
39339578250  2 * 3^2 * 5^3 * 7 * 2497751  82231007094
```

The first of these two, like the earlier example, were found by computer search with PARI/GP. I noticed that their middle odd terms turn up in [A072188](https://oeis.org/A072188):

> Numbers $n$ such that $n$ divides $\sigma(n-1)+\sigma(n)+\sigma(n+1)$, where $\sigma(n)$ is the sum of integer divisors of $n$.

The final of the above examples of perfect 3-runs comes from that sequence.

Comment: Are these the only examples below 6 million?  Gerhard "Is Keeper Of Imperfect Information" Paseman, 2019.04.24.

Comment: @GerhardPaseman: Yes, the above two examples, together with OP's (672, 673), are the only 2 and 3-runs below $10^8$.

Comment: Probably coincidental but your examples all fulfill $\tau(n)=2^m.d$ with $d$ a divisor of a prime.

Comment: My computer checked that there is no other perfect 2-run below $10^{10}$. An observation: in all the known perfect runs, the largest number is a large prime times some small prime factors. I don't know if this could help to find more runs.

Comment: @FrançoisBrunault: I can confirm that there are no other perfect 2-runs and 3-runs below $1.8\times 10^{10}$, nor any perfect 4-runs. The closest for the latter is the run beginning at 113393279 that falls short by 4 of being perfect.